# How to insert object graph using EF code-first

Tags: c#, winforms, ef-code-first

I can not find the cause **why I am failing to insert object graph**

I have an object graph - Promotion with 1..N Flow records.
When I create a new Promotion record, I need to create a related flow record as well.

**This is how I try to do it**

```
var newpromo = new Promotion();
var newflow = new Flow();    
newpromo.Flow.Add(newflow); 

//i thought this should enough to tell EF that newflow's PromotionId
//should be the newly inserted nepromo's Id
newflow.Promotion = newpromo;  
//...
db.Promotions.Attach(newpromo);
db.Entry(newflow).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
```

but **when i call db.SaveChanges() I receive this error**

```
{"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
\"FK_PromotionFlow_Promotions\". The conflict occurred in database \"RepositoryDb\", 
table\"dbo.Promotions\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

**What could be the cause of the problem?**

### DEFINITIONS:

1) This is Promotion and Flow POCO class definitions

```
class Promotion
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public List<PromotionFlow> Flow { get; set; }
    //...other fields
}

class PromotionFlow
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public Int32 PromotionId { get; set; }
    public Promotion Promotion { get; set; }
    //other fields
}
```

2) I have set the mapping using fluent api

```
class PromotionMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Promotion>
{
    public PromotionMapping()
    {
        //Mapping both tables
        HasMany(x => x.Flow).WithRequired(x=>x.Promotion).HasForeignKey(x => x.PromotionId);
        //...other mapping 
    }
}
```

3) In the database I have configured PromotionFlow.PromotionId column as a foreign key to Promotion.Id column

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_PromotionFlow_Promotions] FOREIGN KEY ([PromotionId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Promotions] ([Id])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem... I needed to set object graph parent's (that is Promotion object) entry's state to "Added" (attaching to context was not enough since this was a NEW object)

```
//(...)
db.Promotions.Attach(newpromo);
```

**I was missing THIS row after attaching new Promotion object to context!**

```
db.Entry(newpromotion).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added; //<==THIS ROW
//... dealing with the child (flow) entry states
db.SaveChanges();
```

P.S. the reason I was not using DbContext.DbSet.Add() method was because it sets entity state to Added for all of the objects in the graph (and some of my objects were referencing "Settings" and "Category" type data, that I was not intended to insert once more)

```
db.Promotions.Add(newpromo);
```

P.S. Now it is inserting all of the graph in one db.SaveChanges() call, no need to insert Promotion before inserting Flow objects

Comment: Hmmm, actually it looks like DbSet<T>.Add method works the same as DbContext.Entry(entity<T>).State = ...EntityState.Added, so that I have to check all the related entity states and set the appropriate EntityStates (if I don't want those entities to be inserted in database

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the promo first, then adding the flow to the promo and saving the flow (or the promo).

It sounds like your promo doesn't have an ID to use for the flow because the promo has not yet been inserted into the DB.

Comment: but if I insert an object graph - shouldn't this be something that Entity Framework resolves? Inserts the parent and then retrieves parent id and inserts the child records with the retreived parent id?

Comment: I tried to insert promo before flow and got the same error - thanks, Nathan, it helped me to find the real problem -> I had not set the DbContext.Entry(newpromo).State = Added;